# Change outlook conference room booking auto reply language

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

[image]

This is an auto reply when booking a conference room using outlook. How to change the language that is in this auto reply (yellow color text)? Currently it is in "RU" and I would like it to be it in "EN". I haven't found any methods to do this via "Exchange management shell". Maybe this needs to be done via command line? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: See [calendar - Outlook meetings and auto accept/reply - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/113716/outlook-meetings-and-auto-accept-reply) and the comment below regarding language settings

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, but unfortunately 'Set-Mailbox -Identity "LT-ConfRoom-Andromeda@***.com" -Language en-us'  didn't help..